# Kubernetes namespace migration to another cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks

Let's assume we have a Kubernetes cluster called CLUSTER_01 and DEV namespace on it. I want to recreate this DEV name space in another cluster called CLUSTER_02. What will be the easiest and best way to do this.

Comment: Just curious - what has been tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have standardized Kubernetes deployments via some tools like Jenkins or anything similar then you have set of standard objects you were creating for every deployment, Such as configmap, secret, ingress, deployment, hpa, etc.

Then the easiest way is to dump the objects as YAML to a file and then re-applying them to a new Custer. Though it is not a good practice but the easiest one.

```
kubectl get configmap -n <namespace> -o yaml > CLUSTER_O1_Namespace.yaml
```

Start with lower objects like configmap, secrets, external endpoints then apply the main objects like deployment, ingress, and hpa.

Make sure you have the external dependencies needed by the k8s objects like ingress controller are applied 1st and are identical with your CLUSTER_01.

As @Arghya suggested use [Velero (formerly Heptio Ark)](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero) if you have the bandwidth.

Comment: Thank all for the quick response. 

Another quick question, if I need to make this as a template for cluster provisioning in the future, what will be the best solution. Will Terraform solve my problem.

Comment: Please elaborate your question, what do you mean by cluster provisioning?

Comment: Assume in the future I'm going to have a single cluster with dev, qa, staging as namespaces running on. I need to deploy same set off applications in each of these namespaces. Rather recreating all resources every time one by one in each namespaces, what will be the easiest way for it.

Comment: Terraform + velero is your answer. Terraform will provision your cluster, velero will dump the k8s objects. I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 3):

[Velero (formerly Heptio Ark)](https://velero.io/docs/v1.3.2/) gives you tools to back up and restore your Kubernetes cluster resources and persistent volumes. You can run Velero with a cloud provider or on-premises. Velero lets you:

1. Take backups of your cluster and restore in case of loss.
2. Migrate cluster resources to other clusters.
3. Replicate your production cluster to development and testing clusters.
   Velero consists of:

A server that runs on your cluster

A command-line client that runs locally

Answer (score 0):

Although it is theoretically possible to query the data from etcd datastore and migrate it to another cluster, you'll hit inconsistencies in local settings and variables anyway. The easiest way would be to recreate all resources in the namespace from manifests or Helm charts (whatever you have for them).